# Windows 8 metro app: Accessing the button property

Tags: c#, window, windows-8.1

I am new to windows 8.1 development.
I created the pages below with the button on the xaml page

```
GroupedItemsPage.xaml.cs
GroupedItemsPage.xaml


<Button Style="{StaticResource mystyle}" Click="ItemView_ItemClick" x:Name="Testing">
```

I was thinking that on page load of the xaml page I will be able to have access to the button property
by doing something like this .. Testing.property as we normally do in the windows development environment. This is not happening. I want to be able to style some buttons programmatically.

How can I get the property of the button in the .cs file?

```
Thanks. Here is the xaml page below.

        <GridView
                    x:Name="itemGridView"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Padding="116,137,40,46"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        >
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  >
                                     <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                                </Border>
                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
                                </StackPanel>-->
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource contactSquarePref}" Click="ItemView_ItemClick" x:Name="Testing">
                                    <StackPanel Margin="5" >
                                        <TextBlock Tag="cntCustName" Style="{ThemeResource CntNormalTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Name }"/>                             
                                        <TextBlock Tag="cntCatCode" Style="{ThemeResource CntLrgTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Address}"/>                                
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid GroupPadding="0,0,70,0"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <GridView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2">
                                        <Button Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                            AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                            Click="Header_Click"
                                            Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" >
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContactType}" Margin="0,-11,10,10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-11,0,10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </GridView.GroupStyle>
                </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your XAML. If your button is just a **child element** (i.e. part of your logical tree) or a **named resource** of your page, there'll be no problem, there's a code generation process on build, that creates required fields (in this case `Button Testing`) and finds required elements in `InitializeComponent()` generated method.

But if your button **is a part of control template** the only way to get reference to your element is `GetTemplateChild()` (if you're writing your own control, as this method is protected) or manually observing Visual Tree.

So, **if you have a problem with the child element of your page, past all of your XAML markup here**, as the line in the question above is not enough to find solution. But if you've defined button in control template, look at the second paragraph.